# Magento 2: Where to change the expiration period of Account Confirmation Link?

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account

We have enabled the Account Confirmation link for customers but where can I set the expiration period for confirmation link. There is no configuration for this in admin.

Please guide

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set this in Magento, you will have to do custom development for it.

The account confirmation link for customers never expire. Password reset link on the contrary do expire, for this there is configuration in the backend.

Comment: so what I have understood is that the account confirmation link is valid once but there is no expiration period by default in Magento 2. Is that right?

Comment: yes, thats true